# ¿Cómo saber la posición de un punto decimal en un String?

Tags: c#

Necesito saber en que posición esta el punto decimal en mi String, por ejemplo:

1.500(cadena string)
en este caso el "." estaría en la posición [1].

Estoy intentando esto pero no da resultado:

```
public int funcion(String number)
{
   int tam = number.Length;       
   int pos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        if (number[i].Equals("."))
        {
            return pos;                   
        }
        pos++;
    }

    return pos = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes cambiar "." por '.' ya que lo esperado es un char, recuerda que un caracter de un string va a ser un char, por lo que pasaría lo mismo con cualquier otro. Quedando así:

```
public int funcion(String number)
{
   int tam = number.Length;       
   int pos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        if (number[i].Equals('.'))
        {
            return pos;                   
        }
        pos++;
    }

    return pos = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Estas comparando contra un string usando `""`. Tienes que usar **'** ya que lo que quieres es un char `.`

Comment: gracias @dlag tienes razón!!

Answer (score 3):

Aunque el resultado es correcto, también puedes utilizar el método `IndexOf`:

```
public int funcion(string number)
{
    return number.IndexOf('.');
}
```

Ese método devuelve el índice de un carácter en una cadena o -1 si no existe.

Recuerda que dará una excepción si la cadena está vacía o es nula. Yo lo dejaría así:

```
public int funcion(string number)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number))
        return -1;
    else
        return number.IndexOf('.');
}
```